# c# parallel foreach loop finding index

Tags: c#, loops, parallel.foreach

I am trying to read all lines in a text file and planning to display each line info. How can I find the index for each item inside loop?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
    List<string> list_lines = new List<string>(lines);
    Parallel.ForEach(list_lines, (line, index) =>
      {
         Console.WriteLine(index);
    //   Console.WriteLine(list_lines[index]);
         Console.WriteLine(list_lines[0]);
       });
       Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `index` you have?

Comment: here index shows true or false when debugged.

Comment: Ahh, because as Curtis says, `index` is the third parameter to the callback, not the second.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is [another overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Parallel.ForEach` that gives you the index.

```
Parallel.ForEach(list_lines, (line, state, index) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(index);
        Console.WriteLine(list_lines[(int)index]); // The type of the `index` is Long.
    });
```

Comment: Instead of `list_lines[index]`, wouldn't it be better to use the callback argument (`line`)?

Comment: Absolutely, it's just an example to show that the line is syntactically and semantically valid (`index` is of the right type and semantically represents the index of the current line).

Comment: Could be what I'm looking for, will get back to you once I've tried it out.