# C#( C++ would be cool too) Fastest way to find differences in two large arrays/lists with indexes

Tags: c#, list, performance

**More Details:**
For this problem, I'm specifically looking for the fastest way to do this, in general and specifically in c#. I don't necessarily mean "theoretical" fastest/algorithmic, instead I'm looking for practical implementation speed. In this specific situation, the arrays only have like 1000 elements each, which seems very small, but this computation is going to be running very rapidly and comparing many arrays(it blows up in size very quickly). I ultimately need the indexes of each element that is different.

I can obviously do a very simple implementation like:

```
public List<int> FindDifferences(List<double> Original,List<double> NewList)
{
    List<int> Changes = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0;i<Original.Count;i++)
    {
        if(Original[i]!=NewList[i])
        {
            Changes.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return Changes;
}
```

But  from what I can see, this will be really slow overall since it has to iterate once though each item on the list. Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Specifically, is there a way to do something like a parallel foreach that generates a list of the indexes of changes? [I saw what I think was a similar question asked before, but I didn't quite understand the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713258/c-sharp-parallel-foreach-loop-finding-index) .Or would there be another way to run the calculation on all items of the list simultaneously(or somehow clustered)?

**Assumptions**

1. Each array or list being compared contains data of the same
   type(double int or string), so if array1 holds strings and is
   compared to array2, I know for certain that array2 will only hold
   strings and it will be of the same size(in terms of item count-I can
   see if maybe they are the same byte count too if that could come
   into play).
2. The vast majority of the items in these comparisons will remain the same. My resultant "differences" list will probably only contain a few(1-10) items, if any.

**Concerns**

1) After a comparison is made(old and new list in the block above), the new list will overwrite the old list. If computation time is slower than the time it takes to receive a new message(a new list to compare), I can have a problem with collision:

Lets say I have three lists, **A**,**B**, and **C**. **A** would be my global/"current state" list. When a message is received containing a new list(**B**), it would be the list **B** would be compared to.

In an ideal world, **A** would be compared to **B**, I would receive a list of integers representing the indexes that contain elements different between the two. After the method computes and returns this index list, **A** would become **B**(the values of **B** overwrite the values of **A** as my "current state"). When I receive another message(**C**), this would be compared to my new current state(**A**, but with the values previously belonging to **B**), I'd receive the list of differences and **C**'s values would overwrite **A**'s and become the new current state.  If the comparison between **A** and **B** is still calculating when **C** is received, I would need to make sure the new calculation either:

1. Doesn't happen until after **A** and **B**'s comparison finish and **A** is overwritten with its new values. or
2. The comparison is instead made between **B** and **C**, with **C** overwriting **A** after the comparison finishes(the  difference list is fired off elsewhere, so I'd still receive both change lists)

2) If this comparison between lists can't be sped up, is there somewhere else I can speed up instead? These messages I'm receiving come as an object with three values, an Ascii-encoded byte array, a long string(the already parsed byte array), and a "type"(the name of the list it corresponds to-so I know the data type of its contents). I currently ignore the byte array and parse the string by splitting it at newline characters.

I know this is inefficient, but I have trouble converting the byte array into ints or doubles. The doubles because it has a lot of "noise"(a value of 1.50 could end up coming in as 1.4976789, so I actually have to round it to get its "real" value). The ints because there is no 0 padding, so I don't know the length to chunk the byte array into. Below is an example of what I'm doing:

```
public List<string> ListFromString(string request)
{
    List<string> fulllist = request.Split('\n').ToList<string>();
    return fulllist.GetRange(1, fulllist.Count - 2); //There's always a label tacked on the beginning so I start from 1
}

public List<double> RequestListAsDouble(string request)
{
    List<string> RequestAsString = ListFromString(request);
    List<double> RequestListAsDouble = new List<double>();
    foreach(string requestElement in RequestAsString)
    {
        double requestElementAsDouble = Math.Round(Double.Parse(requestElement),2);
        RequestListAsDouble.Add(requestElementAsDouble);
    }
    return RequestListAsDouble;
}
```

Comment: I see the complexity must be n to achieve your goal so you must go through all your list one (well, both lists but one time for both too). If you want to use threading, you can use thread to loop through the first half of both arrays and compare them, the second thread would loop on the second half of both arrays and compare them.

Comment: You may want to explain why you want to compare the lists in the first place? From the question it seems that A's values will always be update with Bs

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, you are correct, A's values will always update with B's. Changing A's value's isn't the ultimate goal of my project, I'm trying to create "messages" that are fired off to another part program telling me *what* is being changed. Each index corresponds to an object, and I need to tell these objects when one of their values are updated/changed. I don't just need to have the current value of that object's properties, each object runs specific code when certain values are changed and keeps a rolling "log" of changes it has received. This allows me to re-simulate its whole history

Comment: Wouldn't another approach then be to have your objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and its related interfaces/methods and just update the objects? Or do you want all changes to be a kind of a single message?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, that is a really good catch. It's coincidentally how I previously handled the situation. Problem being this is part of a really big project, and my current "data stream"(the messages I'm getting) is archaic(hence why its literally strings that I parse lol). I realized if I kept it that way, once I get access to a new feed(which is down the road), I'd have to rebuild everything. The new feed works by sending those single messages instead of snapshots, so I'm remaking my project with that in mind(and generating my own "messages" in the expected format so I'll be prepared)

Comment: @Anddo, I see the complexity for number of computations must be n in order to do this(unless I put a massive amount of work into building a cache priority system-nty lol), but what I'm not sure of is what about the runtime complexity? If say I fire off all these comparisons at the same time in parallel, is firing off that computation going to take the same time as comparing if the values are equal, or would I be able to speed it up that way? If I can speed it up by doing it in parallel, how would I do that such that I get the indexes of the changes?

Comment: @Fredou, shouldn't have been there lol, thank you. I copy pasted and that got left in by accident.

Comment: if index wasnt needed, Except() could be used. use your code block and do the merge while you compare, after the change.add, do Original[i] = NewList[i] and initialize the **change** capacity with the capacity of the **original** so it wont keep resizing the internal array

Comment: Maybe use a [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) storing the differences in a [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Do what you're doing but manually unroll the loop up to 16x.  I have never found any performance benefit, in C#, of manually unrolling more than 16x, but I have found serious benefits to manually unrolling less than that number.  Alternately, if you're in the mood to learn, C# has vector instructions now that might be able to compare several doubles with one instruction, though the amount depends on your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Your single-threaded comparison of the two parsed lists is probably the fastest way to do it.  It is certainly the easiest. As noted by another poster, you can get some speed advantage by pre-allocating the size of the "Changes" list to be some percentage of the size of your input list.

If you want to try parallel thread comparisons, you should setup "N" number of threads in advance and have them wait for a starting event. "N" is the number of real processors on your system.  Each thread should compare a portion of the lists, and write their answers to the interlocked output list "Changes".  On completion, the threads go back to sleep, waiting for the next starting event.

When all the threads have gone back to their starting positions, the main thread can pick up the "Changes" and pass it along.  Repeat with the next list

Be sure to clean up all the worker threads when your application is supposed to exit - or it won't exit.

There is a lot of overhead in starting and ending threads.  It is all too easy to lose all the processing speed from that overhead.  That's why you would want a pool of worker threads already setup and waiting on an event flag.  Threads only improve processing speed up to the number of real CPUs in the system.

Answer (score 0):

A small optimization would be to initialize the results list with the capacity of the original

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3(v=vs.110).aspx

> If the size of the collection can be estimated, using the
>   List(Int32) constructor and specifying the initial capacity
>   eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations while
>   adding elements to the List.

```
List<int> Changes = new List<int>(Original.Length);
```